# How to enter position with fractional share value Pinescript tradingview

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, back-testing

how can I enter a trade with a fractional amount. For example, at the end of each bar, I want to buy $25 dollars worth of the share. How can I do this when the stock is well above $25. Does pinescript support entering a position with fractional shares?

Follow-up question. After each bar how can I add these shares to the open position without having to close it first?

Comment: I was able to work around adding shares to the order by using strategy.order instead of strategy.enter, however, I still cannot figure out how to create fractional share orders. Thanks!

Comment: Pine supports fractional shares for some crypto symbols only.

Comment: Is there any table or datasheet showing what it is enabled for?

Comment: There is no public info about symbols with fractional qty. From the insider the crypto tickers contains one from the list ("XLM", "USDT", "ADA", "TRX", "IOTA", "XEM" "XRP", "MLN", "BNB", "LTC", "EOS", "QTUM", "NEO" "DASH", "REP", "GNO", "XTZ", "BSV", "BCHSV", "ETC", "BTG" "ETH", "XMR", "XBT", "BCH", "ZEC" "BTC") supports fractoinal contracts